# React/TypeScript/Redux/Thunk reducer gets triggered but state is not updated in redux store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk, state-management

I am trying to populate my redux store state with a list of genres from an API, I can get the action to dispatch to the reducer, but the reducer does not seem to update the state because my console.log in src/components/MovieForm.tsx returns the default state of "null" instead of the array of genres and I do not know why, I am trying to see if the state is updated in src/components/MovieForm.tsx in the setInterval where I am logging the state, maybe the problem is how I am accessing the state? Here are the files:

src/actions/movieActions.ts:

```
import { ActionCreator, Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk';
import { IMovieState } from '../reducers/movieReducer';
import axios from 'axios';

export enum MovieActionTypes {
    ANY = 'ANY',
    GENRE = 'GENRE',
}

export interface IMovieGenreAction {
    type: MovieActionTypes.GENRE;
    genres: any;
}

export type MovieActions = IMovieGenreAction;

/*<Promise<Return Type>, State Interface, Type of Param, Type of Action> */
export const movieAction: ActionCreator<ThunkAction<Promise<any>, IMovieState, void, IMovieGenreAction>> = () => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    try {
      console.log('movieActions called')
      let res = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIE_API_KEY}&language=en-US`)
      console.log(res.data.genres)
      dispatch({
        genres: res.data.genres,
        type: MovieActionTypes.GENRE
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  } 
};
```

src/reducers/movieReducer.ts:

```
import { Reducer } from 'redux';
import { MovieActionTypes, MovieActions } from '../actions/movieActions';

export interface IMovieState {
    //property: any;
    genres: any;
}

const initialMovieState: IMovieState = {
    //property: null,
    genres: null,
};

export const movieReducer: Reducer<IMovieState, MovieActions> = (
    state = initialMovieState,
    action
    ) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case MovieActionTypes.GENRE: {
          console.log('MovieActionTypes.GENRE called')
          return {
            genres: action.genres,
          };
        }
        default:
          console.log('Default action called')
          return state;
      }
  };
```

src/store/store.ts:

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore, Store } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { IMovieState, movieReducer } from '../reducers/movieReducer';

// Create an interface for the application state
export interface IAppState {
  movieState: IMovieState
}

// Create the root reducer
const rootReducer = combineReducers<IAppState>({
  movieState: movieReducer
});

// Create a configure store function of type `IAppState`
export default function configureStore(): Store<IAppState, any> {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, undefined, applyMiddleware(thunk));
  return store;
}
```

src/components/MovieForm.tsx (the file that is supposed to dispatch the action):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import { spacing } from '@material-ui/system';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { CardHeader, TextField, CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { movieAction } from '../actions/movieActions';
import { IAppState } from '../store/store';
import axios from 'axios';


const MovieForm = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const getGenres = () => {
    console.log('actions dispatched')
    dispatch(movieAction())
  }

  const genres = useSelector((state: IAppState) => state.movieState.genres);

  //const [genreChoice, setGenreChoice] = useState('')

  return (
    <>
    <h1>Movie Suggester</h1>
    <Paper elevation={3}>
      <Box p={10}>
        <Card>
          <div>Hello World. </div>
          <Select onChange={() => console.log(genres)}>
            <MenuItem>
              hello
            </MenuItem>
            <br />
            <br />
          </Select>
          <Button onClick={() => {
            getGenres()
            setTimeout(function(){
              console.log(genres)
            }, 5000)
          }}>genres list</Button>
          <Button onClick={() => console.log(axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIE_API_KEY}&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&with_genres=35&page=1`))}>Click me</Button>
        </Card>
      </Box>
    </Paper>
    </>
  )
}


export default MovieForm
```

and here is the src/index.tsx in case the problem is here and I'm unaware:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import theme from './theme';
import App from './App';
import configureStore from './store/store';

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
      <CssBaseline />
        <Router>
          <App />
        </Router>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Thanks for taking a look at this and and attempting to help me see what I am unable to!

Comment: You should install the ReduxDevTools plugin in your browser, if you haven’t already.  It can help you see which actions have been dispatched and what the state looks like so you don’t have to console.log so much

Comment: the `genres` value that gets binded inside your setTimeout function is `null`, just console.log `genres` before the return statement and you'll see how the value changes from null to whatever the response is

Comment: As @diedu mentioned, remove the timeout, add `console.log(genres)` after `const genres = useSelector(...`